# SQL Server - Handle deadlock with retries

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am going this brutal way to handle deadlocks by re-trying 5 times (using SQL Server 2008R2)  and no error handling.

I know it is not delicate, but for the scope of it, can you find any flaws?

Thank you

```
WHILE @retry < 5
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT available
        SELECT 'x','y','z'
        
        BREAK
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF error_number() = 1205 AND @retry < 5
        BEGIN
            SELECT @retry = @retry + 1
            
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.100'
        ELSE    
            BREAK
        END
    END CATCH;
END
```

**EDIT**: I have edited the code following @Charlieface helpfull suggestions.
I have never used TRY/CATCH in SQL server code though. Also THROW is not supported in SQL Server 2008R2

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Yes, deadlocks are batch aborting so it's never going to work anyway. You would need to catch it client-side. But what you should really be doing is dealing with the deadlock. Please [edit] and add table **and index** definitions, deadlock graph, the SQL of the other query that is deadlocking, and please share the two execution plans via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. What does batch aborting mean?

Comment: The whole batch is aborted i.e. execution does not continue and a rollback occurs. Apologies: it is possible to retry if you have a `TRY/CATCH`, see Erland's classic article http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html section 5.2. I still strongly suggest preventing deadlocks occurring in the first place

Comment: Thanx a lot @Charlieface I have never used TRY/CATCH in SQL Server. I am a bit puzzled, in which part of my statement (which exists inside a procedure) should the TRY/CATCH be. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You catch errors on insert, check the error, if it's not the one you want then `THROW;` and you also need to `BREAK;` after the insert. Something like `WHILE ... BEGIN   BEGIN TRY INSERT ...; BREAK; END TRY BEGIN CATCH IF error_number() <> 1205 THROW; END CATCH; END;`

Comment: You are very helpfull @Charlieface. Throw is not supported in SQL Server 2008R2 unfortunately. I will try and edit my initial post based on your suggestions in the next minutes.

Comment: @PanosPlat If TRY and CATCH are supported, then THROW certainly is. All introduced in 2005 i believe. Flaws? First, you have pseudo-code. Next, your psuedo-code isn't complete. There is no point to addressing flaws at this point. It appears you do EAT the error completely but that just might be an omission.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for your reply. In this stage, I do not want to log or tackle the errors. The decision is to just retry 5 times. If 5 times fails, nothing happens. In that scenario, I wonder whether my code is OKish.

Comment: I also strongly suggest you upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server. 2008R2 was end-of-life'd a while ago already